# Smallest graph with non-disjointly generated automorphism group

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, algorithms, automorphism-group

Consider the automorphism group $\text{Aut}(H)$ of a graph $H$. I say that $\text{Aut}(H)$ is disjointly generated if there exists a set of generators $A$ of $\text{Aut}(H)$ such that for each vertex $v$ of $H$, there exists at most one generator $g \in A$ with $g(v) \neq v$.

I'm interested in the size $n_{\text{min}}$ of the smallest graph $H$ such that $\text{Aut}(H)$ is *not* disjointly generated. **Are there any lower bounds (either by mathematical proof or reference to literature) on $n_{\text{min}}$?** I'm particularly interested in whether $n_{\text{min}} > 8$.

It is easy to see that $n_{\text{min}} > 4$ by brute-forcing all graphs with $\leq 4$ vertices. However, this approach quickly becomes infeasible to do by hand. One can of course design an algorithm to compute this automatically, but any approach I've come up with is both hard to implement and becomes infeasible even to a very fast computer before $n=8$. I would also accept an answer that discusses a reasonably quick algorithm to verify that $n_{\text{min}} > 8$, but prefer mathematical proofs or references to literature.

Comment: If $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is disjointly generated, shouldn't it be abelian? (Any two generators commute, because any two generators permute disjoint sets of vertices.) So it seems like $\operatorname{Aut}(K_3) = S_3$ is a counterexample, or am I confused?

Comment: @Misha Ah, you're absolutely right! I was actually thinking about another property of the automorphism group, and thought I had proven it was equivalent to being disjointly generated. It seems I made a serious error in that proof. Thank you for your help! I might re-post the question with the property I was originally interested in.

Comment: @Misha Also, feel free to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I am very curious about what the original question was now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\operatorname{Aut}(H)$ is disjointly generated, it should be abelian. (Any two generators commute, because any two generators permute disjoint sets of vertices.) So the smallest graph with a non-disjointly-generated automorphism group is $K_3$, because $\operatorname{Aut}(K_3) = S_3$, and $n_{\min} =3$.